# webpack not transpiling my .ts as expected

Tags: node.js, webpack, visual-studio-code

I am using webpack on the back end (nodejs) of my application, principally to     transpile my .ts to .js. It ain't working though. It processes the app.ts which requires the controllers folder, but webpack complains:

```
ERROR in ./app.ts
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./controllers in C:\Users\markn\Documents\source\ftct
@ ./app.ts 3:18-42
```

An extract of my webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = [{
    {
        // back end
        context: app,
        entry: {
            app: ['webpack/hot/dev-server', './app.ts']
        },
        target: 'node',
        devtool: 'source-map',
        output: {
            path: app,
            filename: 'app.js'
        },
        externals: nodeModules, 
        module: {
            loaders: [
                { test: /\.ts(x?)$/, loader: 'babel-loader!ts-loader' },
                { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'ng-annotate!babel!jshint', exclude: /node_modules/ },
                { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.BannerPlugin('require("source-map-support").install();',
                { raw: true, entryOnly: false })
        ]
    }
];
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not to worry, found the answer. Well, stumbled across it while staring at the code. I was missing this from my config:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
}
```